# Java Class modification order using BCEL

Tags: java, jvm, classloader, bcel

When does a java library ([bcel](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/) in my case.) modify other code?

Will this happen before or after a class in question is loaded by classloader's bootstrap process?

Answer (score 2):

BCEL loads classes **as files** after your application has started, and once you have a `JavaClass` reference you can start modifying the original class. No system ClassLoader loads the class you are about to modify in any way.